# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'state_dict' in Azure ML Studio with PyTorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I'm a beginner at PyTorch and I've been trying to set up a PyTorch model in Azure ML Studio. The code runs fine in Google Colab but in Azure ML notebook, I get this error:

```
File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38_PT_TF/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/training_io.py:268, in TrainerIOMixin.save_checkpoint(self, filepath, weights_only)
    267 def save_checkpoint(self, filepath, weights_only: bool = False):
--> 268     checkpoint = self.dump_checkpoint(weights_only)
    270     if self.is_global_zero:
    271         # do the actual save
    272         try:

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38_PT_TF/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/training_io.py:362, in TrainerIOMixin.dump_checkpoint(self, weights_only)
    360     # save native amp scaling
    361     if self.use_amp and NATIVE_AMP_AVALAIBLE and not self.use_tpu:
--> 362         checkpoint['native_amp_scaling_state'] = self.scaler.state_dict()
    364 # add the module_arguments and state_dict from the model
    365 model = self.get_model()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'state_dict'
```

Model code:

```
class EvaluationModel(pl.LightningModule):
  def __init__(self,learning_rate=1e-3,batch_size=1024,layer_count=10):
    super().__init__()
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.learning_rate = learning_rate
    layers = []
    for i in range(layer_count-1):
      layers.append((f"linear-{i}", nn.Linear(808, 808)))
      layers.append((f"relu-{i}", nn.ReLU()))
    layers.append((f"linear-{layer_count-1}", nn.Linear(808, 1)))
    self.seq = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict(layers))

  def forward(self, x):
    return self.seq(x)

  def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    x, y = batch['binary'], batch['eval']
    y_hat = self(x)
    loss = F.l1_loss(y_hat, y)
    self.log("train_loss", loss)
    return loss

  def configure_optimizers(self):
    return torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=self.learning_rate)

  def train_dataloader(self):
    dataset = EvaluationDataset(count=LABEL_COUNT)
    return DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=self.batch_size, num_workers=2, pin_memory=True)

configs = [
           {"layer_count": 4, "batch_size": 512},
          #  {"layer_count": 6, "batch_size": 1024},
           ]
for config in configs:
  version_name = f'{int(time.time())}-batch_size-{config["batch_size"]}-layer_count-{config["layer_count"]}'
  logger = pl.loggers.TensorBoardLogger("lightning_logs", name="chessml", version=version_name)
  trainer = pl.Trainer(gpus=1,precision=16,max_epochs=1,auto_lr_find=True,logger=logger)
  model = EvaluationModel(layer_count=config["layer_count"],batch_size=config["batch_size"],learning_rate=1e-3)
  # trainer.tune(model)
  # lr_finder = trainer.tuner.lr_find(model, min_lr=1e-6, max_lr=1e-3, num_training=25)
  # fig = lr_finder.plot(suggest=True)
  # fig.show()
  trainer.fit(model)
  break
```

Model code is from https://towardsdatascience.com/train-your-own-chess-ai-66b9ca8d71e4

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it seems like there is some issue with your checkpoint. Could you try loading your model using `torch.load` API and see if that works?